# What is the reason for the /a /b prefixes of git diff

Tags: git, git-diff

I've been using Git for some years now and always wondered why `git diff` prefixes the names of modified files with `a/` and `b/`. I expected to eventually stumble upon a use-case where it is useful, but until now it was always annoying and never helpful.

What is it good for? Why is this enabled by default? In which situations is it useful?

Comment: I did not care for the reason, but [I've got](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516234/2750743) what I was googled here for ^_^

Answer (score 72):

As mentioned in the [diff man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), `a/` and `b/` represent the prefix to differentiate source and destination.

Actually, you have the options:

> ```
> --no-prefix
> ```
>
> Do not show any source or destination prefix.
>
> ```
> --src-prefix=<prefix>
> ```
>
> Show the given source prefix instead of "a/".
>
> ```
> --dst-prefix=<prefix>
> ```
>
> Show the given destination prefix instead of "b/"

---

[Gringo Suave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450917/gringo-suave) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764953/what-is-the-reason-for-the-a-b-prefixes-of-git-diff/6764988#comment126530277_6764988):

> Went with:
>
> ```
> git diff --src-prefix="SRC " --dst-prefix="DST "
> ```
>
> to make double-click select and paste work.

---

By the way, it does not have to *always* be `a/` and `b/`:

With Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6fd04375f9196f8b203d442f235bd96a1a068cc), "[`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/396430b5a73f60acc2ce8365a9edfe6923014ca3/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> and friends learned two extra configuration variables, `diff.srcPrefix` and `diff.dstPrefix`.

See [commit 178401d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/178401dc25cf8c3f1a716b852b14dafa79367646) (15 Mar 2024) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 7fdc265](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7fdc2656331f051a673a61444051cde58044ceeb) (15 Mar 2024) by [Peter Hutterer (`whot`)](https://github.com/whot).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 396430b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/396430b5a73f60acc2ce8365a9edfe6923014ca3), 28 Mar 2024)</sup>

> ### [`diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7fdc2656331f051a673a61444051cde58044ceeb): add diff.srcPrefix and diff.dstPrefix configuration variables
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Peter Hutterer</sup>

> Allow the default prefixes "`a/`" and "`b/`" to be tweaked by the `diff.srcPrefix` and `diff.dstPrefix` configuration variables.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7fdc2656331f051a673a61444051cde58044ceeb/Documentation/config/diff.txt#L114-L119):

> ### `diff.srcPrefix`
>
> If set, '`git diff`' uses this source prefix. Defaults to "`a/`".
>
> ### `diff.dstPrefix`
>
> If set, '`git diff`' uses this destination prefix. Defaults to "`b/`".

`diff-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7fdc2656331f051a673a61444051cde58044ceeb/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L868-L870):

> ### `--default-prefix`
>
> Use the default source and destination prefixes ("`a/`" and "`b/`").
> This overrides configuration variables such as `diff.noprefix`,
> `diff.srcPrefix`, `diff.dstPrefix`, and `diff.mnemonicPrefix`.

Comment: @manojlds: Thanks, we were writing practically at the same time anyway. Note: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/175850 mentions that the path prefixes of the diff machinery used to by hardwired to "`a/`" for the source prefix and "`b/`" for the destination prefix.

Comment: @Denji what version of Git are you using on your OS X?

Comment: i love how bad the defaults for everything on git are. `a` and `b` for origin and destination... how is that clear? anyway, you can also disable for good with `git config --global diff.noprefix true`

Comment: Is there any way to disable the prefix shown by `git add --patch`?

Comment: @JFlo No sure: would the diff.noprefix config help? (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-diffnoprefix)

Comment: @VonC, that does not affect `git add --patch`.

Comment: Went with `git diff --src-prefix="SRC " --dst-prefix="DST "` to make double-click select and paste work.

Comment: @GringoSuave Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 56):

If you don't find it useful, you can turn it off with:

```
git config --global diff.noprefix true
```

Comment: But no property to permanently set it to something meaningful?

Comment: It would be nice if there was a similar option for the diffs seen when using `git add --patch`.  I love to dbl-click these names for quick pasting into konsole, but it's annoying to always have to trim this stupid, useless prefix.

Answer (score 30):

These directory prefixes are there basically for compatibility and chosen as a sensible defaults.  Explanation follows.

### Before git

Before git (and other [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)), the workflow to create a patch for multiple files could have been, for example, the following:

- Let's say you have a source code of a project `asdf` in a directory `asdf-source.latest`.
- You copy the directory to a new directory (e.g. `asdf-source.new`, ideally [hard-linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) the files inside).
- Now you can make all your changes in `asdf-source.new`, try to compile the code, test it, etc.
- After you're done, you create a patch using e.g. `diff -r asdf-source.latest asdf-source.new >new_feature.patch`.  The output evolved in time as well.  Apart from other things, git uses an "unified" output by default, which might be acquired using diff's `-u` parameter.

Now you can see the patch has paths to changed files using the directory names.

The person (or build script, and so on) applying your patch will then use `patch` instead of using `git apply` or `git am`.  In order for the command to find proper files, the directory name must be removed from the path, using patch's `-pN` option (N shows the number of directory names and separators to remove).  In the above case, the command used could be `patch -p1 <new_feature.patch`.  This makes it possible for the patch creator to use his/her own directory names.

If you ever encounter a script patching some project using a lot of patches (usually used for [back-ported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backport) patches for stable package versions in Linux distributions for example), the patches may vary in the format.
The `patch` command is able to detect those formats properly, but it is a little bit harder with the paths (how many directories to remove).
Some problems with that:

- Forcing developers to use 0 directories is not very nice.
- Having `patch` look for the file might be dangerous (as it may find a different file).

So having everyone sending patches that can be applied with `patch -p1` seems the most sensible way to take.

### Back to git

When git was created, it adopted sensible defaults (which are compatible with most project's submission guidelines, mainly kernel) for such options.  Thanks to this you are able to use git and send a properly formatted patch to someone who uses `patch` to apply it and vice versa (git is able to handle `diff`-created patches as well).  Having "a" and "b" as prefixes in particular saves space (and a tiny percentage of bandwidth) while keeping everything working.

You can set `git config diff.mnemonicprefix true` in order for git to use different prefixes depending on what you are comparing (see `git help config` for further details).

Comment: With git your claim /"Forcing developers to use 0 directories is not very nice"/ makes no sense. There's no a vs b. /"Having patch look for the file might be dangerous (as it may find different file)"/ makes also no sense since there is no old dir a and new dir b.

`-p0` is the patch default. With `-p1` you'll have to type more. So `diff.noprefix true` is a meaningful default.

Comment: Saying "Forcing developers to use 0 directories", I mean the use case explained in the start of the section.  I was easier to have it in 2 directories and the default output would be then applied with `-p1`. About the "finding a different file", that is of course not that easy, but having `-p0` does not strip anything which means that full paths (e.g. `/etc/hosts`) will be kept and treated as such.  This is of course handled in current patch implementation.

Comment: @rurban According to the man page of patch(1) version 2.7.1, the default is not `-p0`.  Not using `-p` (or `--strip`) option at all will strip all the directory names, so with `/u/howard/src/blurfl/blurfl.c` "not specifying -p at all just gives you blurfl.c."

Comment: You are right. -p0 is required. Sorry. With `diff.noprefix true` it's also much easier to copy&paste the file.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to add `git diff --no-prefix` to your **.gitconfig** manually, just add the following:

```
[diff]
noprefix = true
```

Comment: This works, but breaks `git apply` by terms of creating unusable `git diff`s; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57340649/ --- git is retarded.

Answer (score 6):

It is to differentiate source and destination. You can also change it to be more meaningful:

> --src-prefix=`<prefix>`
>
> ```
> Show the given source prefix instead of "a/".
> ```
>
> --dst-prefix=`<prefix>`
>
> ```
> Show the given destination prefix instead of "b/".
> ```

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Comment: you guys created almost the very same answer 1min apart!