# Which commits do a/ and b/ corresponds to in the output of git diff?

Tags: git, git-diff

I am facing a similar example as in this tutorial:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-diff

Executing git diff:

```
git diff commit1 commit2
```

I get the following output:

```
diff --git a/diff_test.txt b/diff_test.txt
index 6b0c6cf..b37e70a 100644
--- a/diff_test.txt
+++ b/diff_test.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-this is a git diff test example
+this is a diff example
```

How do I know which commit is a and which is b?

Comment: `a/` and `b/` are know as the source and destination prefixes, respectively. They're just markers associated to (in your specific case) `commit1` and `commit2`, respectively.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6764953/2541573

Comment: I agree, but who is a and who is b, and why?

Comment: In your case, `a/` corresponds to `commit1` and `b/` corresponds to `commit2`.

Comment: Ok, can you please change your comment to an answer, so I can mark it as answer?
commit1 is a, but because it is marked with "-" signs, it confused me and I interpreted the change on the other way arround. When using diff to compare two commits, it seems that it is better to use diff olderCommit newerCommit

Comment: Check out the question I link to. Could we not close yours as a duplicate of it?

Comment: If you prefer.. :)
I voted to close